# anagrams can be handled with regexp

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, regex-group

here is my requirement

```
const input = 'abcadbca';
const required = 'bca';
```

the input contains 3 possibility anagrams as:`abc`,`bca`,`bca`;
is this all can be selected using `regexp`?
i tried it, but got not result:

```
const str = 'abcadbca';
const reg = str.match(/(a|b|c)/g);

console.log(reg);
```

result expectation: `[a,b,c,][b,c,a],[b,c,a]`;
result should be `[a,b,c],[b,c,a]` - first 2 match are overlapping so first match is taken for the account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know in advance the characters that constitute the anagrams you're expecting, as indicated by your `required` constant already consisting of characters `b`, `c` and `a`, you can build a regex with each character included in a sub-pattern that expects it in one of the following 3 characters with a lookahead pattern:

```js
const str = 'abcadbca';
console.log(str.match(/(?=.{0,2}b)(?=.{0,2}c)(?=.{0,2}a).{3}/g));
```

This outputs:

```
[
  "abc",
  "bca"
]
```